# Launch an iPhone app in an international market

Tags: ios, app-store

I´m planning to launch an app for the iPhone. I wonder if there is a way to launch the app, country by country? For example, if I first begin with the Norwegian market and after 4 four weeks I launch the app in the US. If this is possible, how can I do this step by step?

And also if the mentioned procedure above is possible, will the app appear in some kind of “new releases” in the App store, every time I add a new country?

Answer (score 3):

When you go to the Manage your Apps section in iTunes Connect, Rights and Pricing subsection, you have the chance to choose the markets where your app is available (follow the link that says "specific stores").

So, you can start with making it available on the Norwegian market, then add another one at some later point, etc., by simply going there and adding more markets.

Answer (score 0):

Each country has it's own AppStore, and it is true that you can add and delete the app from each country's AppStore.

As for new releases, the newly released app in each country would only appear in the new releases list for the country that you actually release it in.